# Having problem to activate the built-in webcam on arch

Tags: arch-linux

I have a problem activating my webcam. I have a Surface Pro 6 and running Arch as OS. I think the webcam is recognized, but I am not able to use/enable it.

As an example cheese, firefox withs Jitsi and OBS are not able to use my webcam.

Learning from other posts, I think this information could be relevant.
My user is part of the group video.

I did get the video starting cheese via the terminal. I did get the error:

```
(cheese:1105): cheese-WARNING **: 09:13:26.353: Device '/dev/video11' has no supported format: ../gst-plugins-good/sys/v4l2/gstv4l2object.c(3951): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin35/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
Call to TRY_FMT failed for NV12 @ 5120x3840: Invalid argument
```

the command `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` returns following:

```
ipu3-imgu (PCI:0000:00:05.0):
    /dev/media1

Intel IPU3 CIO2 (PCI:0000:00:14.3):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media0

ipu3-imgu (PCI:3a stat):
    /dev/video8
    /dev/video13

ipu3-imgu (PCI:input):
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video9

ipu3-imgu (PCI:output):
    /dev/video6
    /dev/video11

ipu3-imgu (PCI:parameters):
    /dev/video5
    /dev/video10

ipu3-imgu (PCI:viewfinder):
    /dev/video7
    /dev/video12
```

`ls -l /dev/video*`:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  0 May  4 19:47 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  1 May  4 19:47 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 15 May  4 19:47 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 16 May  4 19:47 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 17 May  4 19:47 /dev/video12
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 18 May  4 19:47 /dev/video13
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  2 May  4 19:47 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  3 May  4 19:47 /dev/video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  9 May  4 19:47 /dev/video4
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 10 May  4 19:47 /dev/video5
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 11 May  4 19:47 /dev/video6
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 12 May  4 19:47 /dev/video7
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 13 May  4 19:47 /dev/video8
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 14 May  4 19:47 /dev/video9
```

I am not able to post the dmesg output so I used grep:
`sudo dmesg | grep [vV]ideo`:

```
[    0.220785] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.473002] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    1.797797] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    3.286851] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    3.291804] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input24
```

THank you for your help :-)

Comment: `grep -i 'video'` is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: my user is part of the group video. I think that means I have already access.